# filepicker.io convert

Tags: filepicker.io

I have a file picker url

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/wIilPqwFSxCg8zZdsYTN?dl=false

I then make some edits to this and save it back using the a CURL command.  This works as excepted.

The problem I am having is when I use the convert option to create a thumbnail, it does not create thumbnail from the new image but the old one.

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/wIilPqwFSxCg8zZdsYTN/convert?h=150&w=150&fit=crop&dl=false

Comment: My guess is that there is a caching issue somewhere along the line. Did you ever try creating a converted image of the original before doing the edit?

Comment: yes I do converts before the I do the edit.  This is a standard part of the application.  Anyway to flush the cache?

Comment: I went ahead and made caching on our end less aggressive, should be going out later today to address the issue

Comment: Thanks very much. I shall retest and let you know

Comment: do you mean that it did not save the thumbnail as a separate file?